# what type returned when using HttpClient.GetAsync().Result;

Tags: c#

I'm using

```
var response = HttpClient.GetAsync(myurl).Result;
```

in a function, but I want "response" to be global variable.

If I declare it globally, what type is it?

```
<HttpResponseType??> response;
```

Comment: When you need to know the return type of a function from the Framework, check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: By the way, Visual Studio shows you the type on hover: http://i.imgur.com/sKKJOw9.png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HttpClient.GetAsync(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. You get the [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the task, so the type is [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you were to have a field for this, it could look like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response;
```